# Should I use different case-spellings for case-insensitive directories in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, case-sensitive

Unfortunately, I’ve got case-insensitive servers that cannot be replaced in the short term. Some directories need to be excluded from crawling, so I have to `Disallow` them in my `robots.txt`. Let’s take `/Img/` as example. If I keep it all lower case…

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /img/
```

… it does not map to the actual physical path, and addresses with `/Img/` or `/IMG/` are not applied the `Disallow` directive. Crawlers will treat these variations as distinct paths.

It’s fun to look at [Microsoft’s robots.txt](http://www.microsoft.com/robots.txt) in this matter. They probably use IIS servers, and SERPs are just full of disallowed addresses–only with other cases.

What can I do?
Is it valid (and effectual) to state the following?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /Img/
Disallow: /img/
Disallow: /IMG/
```

Answer (score 5):

The original robots.txt specification doesn't say anything about typecase in file paths, but according to [Google's robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), file paths are definitely case-sensitive. Google clearly states that "Disallow: /img/" only blocks "/img/", not "/Img/" or "/IMG/". Your solution is definitely valid, and will solve the problem.

That being said, I would only resort to this solution if I had reason to believe the alternate-case URLs were actually being crawled, and they were causing a problem. You can easily turn your robots.txt file into an unmaintainable mess otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

As the [`Disallow` field](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format) takes (beginnings of) URL paths as value, and [URL paths are case-sensitive](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/51901/17633), your assumption is correct.

So yes, if you want to block all URLs whose paths start with case-insensitive `/img`/, you’d need to add:

```
Disallow: /img/
Disallow: /IMG/
Disallow: /Img/
Disallow: /IMg/
Disallow: /ImG/
Disallow: /iMg/
Disallow: /iMG/
Disallow: /imG/
```